# Simplify large equation system, with conditions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I have a large matrix $Q$ where $0≤Q_{ij}≤1$ and $\sum_iQ_{ij}=1$ for $j=1,2,3,4$, and all entries depend on 6 variables $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Is it possible to simplify this huge matrix? `Q={{0,1/3,1/3,1/3},{(c^2+d e+e^2+b (c-e-f)+2 a f-d f-3 e f+2 f^2-c (d+2 e+3 f))/(4 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f))),(3 c^2-d e+3 e^2+c (d-6 e-5 f)-2 a f+d f-5 e f+2 f^2+b (-c+e+f))/(12 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f))),(3 c^2-d e+3 e^2+c (d-6 e-5 f)-2 a f+d f-5 e f+2 f^2+b (-c+e+f))/(12 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f))),(3 c^2-d e+3 e^2+c (d-6 e-5 f)-2 a f+d f-5 e f+2 f^2+b (-c+e+f))/(12 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f)))},{(c^2+2 b e-d e+2 e^2+a (c-e-f)+d f-3 e f+f^2-c (d+3 e+2 f))/(4 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f))),(3 c^2-2 b e+d e+2 e^2+c (d-5 e-6 f)-d f-5 e f+3 f^2+a (-c+e+f))/(12 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f))),(3 c^2-2 b e+d e+2 e^2+c (d-5 e-6 f)-d f-5 e f+3 f^2+a (-c+e+f))/(12 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f))),(3 c^2-2 b e+d e+2 e^2+c (d-5 e-6 f)-d f-5 e f+3 f^2+a (-c+e+f))/(12 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f)))},{(2 c^2+2 c d-3 c e+e^2-b (c+e-f)-3 c f-2 e f+f^2-a (c-e+f))/(4 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f))),(2 c^2-2 c d-5 c e+3 e^2+b (c+e-f)-5 c f-6 e f+3 f^2+a (c-e+f))/(12 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f))),(2 c^2-2 c d-5 c e+3 e^2+b (c+e-f)-5 c f-6 e f+3 f^2+a (c-e+f))/(12 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f))),(2 c^2-2 c d-5 c e+3 e^2+b (c+e-f)-5 c f-6 e f+3 f^2+a (c-e+f))/(12 (c^2+(e-f)^2-2 c (e+f)))}}`.
[image: The complicated matrix M]

Comment: Try `FullSimplify` command ?. You have large matrix `Q`,but yours matrix is `M` ?

Comment: Oh yea my bad. Q and M is the same. It is corrected now